# support dynamic key with springfox swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springfox

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Sample API")
@ApiImplicitParams(value = {
            @ApiImplicitParam(dataType = "string", name = "x",, required = false, paramType = "form", allowMultiple = true),
            @ApiImplicitParam(dataType = "__file", name = "y", , required = false, paramType = "form", allowMultiple = true)
})
@PostMapping(value = "/{upload}", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity upload(HttpServletRequest request) {

    //process request

}
```

Unable to get below CURL equivalent using above Spring fox Swagger (2.9.2)

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/upload \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F 'x1=@path\1.txt' \
  -F 'x2=@path\2.txt' \
  -F x3=val3    \
  -F x4=val4
```

Needed support for dynamic keys equivalent to a controller that could accept `Map<String,String>`, `Map<String,MultipartFile>` both.

Won't it be possible before Open API 3 support is added to springfox swagger ?